# How to display user databases only in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

how to display user databases in sqlserver

i queried as select sys.databases it displays all including msdb temp and all.

i need only user cretaed databases.

is there any query like : select * from sys.databases where type='u' ??

Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason it needs to be more advanced than just this?

```
SELECT * FROM sysdatabases WHERE name NOT IN('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify them with their `owner name`. In order to do that, you should join `sys.databases` with `sys.server_principals`.

Recent versions can have ReportServer databases as well with contains `$` sign in name.

```
select
  d.name
  ,d.database_id
from
  sys.databases d
join
  sys.server_principals p
  on p.sid = d.owner_sid
where
  p.name <> 'sa' and d.name not like '%$%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Or per this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4f394da7-3596-4b59-9caa-ecc8443fc9e8):

```
select * from sys.sysdatabases where dbid>4 and [name] not like '$'
```